# Return Dynamic Array whilst Filtering another Dynamic Array

Tags: excel

The below image summarises my data, my desired result and my problem;

[image]

I'd like to create a single cell list of all unique Bars for a list of unique Foos dynamically.

The formula I have in h2 give me my desired result, however, it isn't itself a dynamic array (which means it won't automatically grow with my data as columns A&B expand).

I've tried to apply the formula dynamically in G2 but get an "#N/A" error.

**E2** `=UNIQUE(DROP(FILTER(A:A,A:A<>""),1))`

**G2**
`=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,UNIQUE(FILTER(B:B,A:A=E2#)))`

**H2**
`=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,UNIQUE(FILTER(B:B,A:A=E2)))`

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to involve `byrow` or `map`

Comment: @chrisneilsen that's just the pointer I needed! Thanks.